# CSS pseudo element between elements

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with CSS pseudo element `:after` or `:before` to clear floats between elements? Or is there another way I could clear the floats between `<div class="float">` and `<section class="inner">`?

HTML and CSS looks like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
section.wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  float: left;
  border-top: solid 0px white;
  border-right: solid 5px white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px white;
  border-left: solid 0px white;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>

    <!-- CLEAR FLOAT HERE -->

    <section class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Add `clear: left` to `.inner` class.

Comment: @Mr_Green ! that's it! Wanna post it as answer please, so I can accept yours

Comment: caramba, it is your wish. But I won't post it as answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure with `clear: both` or `clear: left`:

```
.inner {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear `section's` `:before`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
section.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
section.wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  float: left;
  border-top: solid 0px white;
  border-right: solid 5px white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px white;
  border-left: solid 0px white;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
border-right: 0;
}
.inner:before {
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>

<!-- CLEAR FLOAT HERE -->

<section class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put clear:both before inner section, like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
section.inner:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  float: left;
  border-top: solid 0px white;
  border-right: solid 5px white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px white;
  border-left: solid 0px white;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>

    <!-- CLEAR FLOAT HERE -->

    <section class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the original question, it's possible to place the `::before`/`::after` pseudo element between child elements with flexbox layout and `order` property. E.g.:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
section.wrap:after {
  content: 'I am an inserted pseudo!';
  display: block;
  order: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border-top: solid 0px white;
  border-right: solid 5px white;
  border-bottom: solid 5px white;
  border-left: solid 0px white;
}

div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
    border-right: 0;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>

    <!-- NO NEED TO CLEAR FLOATS, BUT WE CAN PUT A PSEUDO HERE -->

    <section class="inner">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </section>
</section>
```